# How to add an item to ext js panel on click of the panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I want to add a button into a panel to the exact position where I clicked.

SO I have tried like as follows, this the structure of my `Ext.widget` element

Ext.widget({
        xtype   : 'mz-form-widget',
        itemId: 'shopableImage',
        anchor: "100%",

```
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        listeners: {
            controller: '',
            change: function (cmp) {
                controller = cmp;
                cmp.up('#shopableImage').updatePreview();
            }
        }
    },


    items: [
        {
            xtype: "tacofilefield",
            itemId: "imageUploadButton",
            text: "Upload images"
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            width: 350,
            height: 350,
            itemId:'container',
            id:'container',
            bodyStyle:{"background":"url('http://www.easyvectors.com/assets/images/vectors/vmvectors/jeans-girl-vector-27.jpg')","border":"1px solid #eee"},
            listeners: {
                click: {
                    element: 'el', //bind to the underlying el property on the panel
                    fn: function(a,b,c,d){ 
                        console.log(a.browserEvent.clientX - b.offsetLeft);
                        console.log(a.browserEvent.clientY - b.offsetTop);
                        console.log(c);
                       this.down('#container').addItem({"xtype":"button","text":"+"});
                    }
                },
                dblclick: {
                    element: 'body', //bind to the underlying body property on the panel
                    fn: function(){ console.log('dblclick body'); }
                }
            }
        }
```

The following line throwing me error.
**`this.down('#container').addItem({"xtype":"button","text":"+"});`**
**UPDATE**

```
this.down('#container')
```

is returning null.

Please give me your suggestions regarding this?

Comment: what error are you seeing?

Comment: Cant call function addItem of undefined.
I have updated the question details.

Comment: Because 'this' is the container already, see Saki's recent comments just do this.add()

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't worked for me. Do have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here, one is causing the error and another is a potential time bomb:

1. `addItem` does not exist, the correct method name is `add`
2. You use id's on components and that is a very bad practice, however, it does not the immediate cause of the error

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd opinion.
but still add is also not working.
I have problem with the line:  `this.down('#container')`
This line returns me null object, and I cant do add/addItem to a undefined object.

Comment: The listener is installed on the container itself so `this.add(...)` should do it.

Comment: this.down('#container') as null looks as a scope problem can you try

    {element: 'el', scope: this, fn: function () {...}}

Comment: for `this.down('#container')` I am still getting null.

Comment: Did you try `this.add()`? If you go down from container sure you don't get that container. It cannot be child of itself.